# Android - Singleton view / Replicating states

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view that contains two vote buttons, a thumbs up, and thumbs down.

One of these buttons can be active at a time, and clicking one button, disables the other.

All of this works fine, however these buttons can be used in various places, but all represent the same item.

Is it possible to replicate the state of these buttons across all instances of the view? So that when it is clicked in one place, that voting state is automatically shown in the others?

Any help would be appreciated here.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is a sample of my code. This is working for each individual instance, however they are all acting independently.

```
public class VoteButtons extends RelativeLayout {

    OnVoteListener mListener;

    String playedItemId = null;

    View rootView;

    @Bind(R.id.vote_up_button)
    ImageButton voteUpButton;

    @Bind(R.id.vote_down_button)
    ImageButton voteDownButton;

    Context mContext;

    VoteState state = VoteState.VOTED_NONE;

    enum VoteState {
        VOTED_UP, VOTED_DOWN, VOTED_NONE
    }

    public VoteButtons(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public VoteButtons(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.mContext = context;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vote_buttons, this, true);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.vote_down_button)
    public void onClickVoteDown(ImageButton voteDownButton) {

        if(state == VoteState.VOTED_NONE) {
            state = VoteState.VOTED_DOWN;

            if(mListener != null && playedItemId != null)         mListener.onVoteDown(playedItemId);

            } else {

                state = VoteState.VOTED_NONE;

                if(mListener != null && playedItemId != null) mListener.onVoteCancel(playedItemId);
        }

        updateButtonStates();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.vote_up_button)
    public void onClickVoteUp(ImageButton voteDownButton) {

        if(state == VoteState.VOTED_NONE) {
            state = VoteState.VOTED_UP;

            if(mListener != null && playedItemId != null) mListener.onVoteUp(playedItemId);

       } else {

            if(mListener != null && playedItemId != null) mListener.onVoteCancel(playedItemId);

            state = VoteState.VOTED_NONE;
        }

        updateButtonStates();
    }

    private void updateButtonStates() {
        switch(state) {
            case VOTED_UP:
                Drawable greenVoteUpDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_black_24dp).mutate());

                DrawableCompat.setTint(greenVoteUpDrawable, Color.parseColor("#7FD473"));

                voteUpButton.setImageDrawable(greenVoteUpDrawable);
            break;

            case VOTED_DOWN:
                Drawable greenVoteDownDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_black_24dp).mutate());

                DrawableCompat.setTint(greenVoteDownDrawable, Color.parseColor("#ED5756"));

                voteDownButton.setImageDrawable(greenVoteDownDrawable);
            break;

            case VOTED_NONE:

                // Show original drawables
                voteUpButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_black_24dp));
                voteDownButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_thumb_down_black_24dp));

                break;
        }
    }

    public void setOnVoteListener(OnVoteListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnVoteListener {
        void onVoteUp(String playedItemId);

        void onVoteDown(String playedItemId);

        void onVoteCancel(String playedItemId);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could store the state in a static field?

Comment: Are you using it in list, and across different activities/fragments?

Comment: Yes, one case is in a list (however only on the first item), and another is on the main page of my app, but constantly displayed.

Comment: If you show your code as how you have made this custom view, then it would help. Where you're coding to disable other button?  just put that snippet in your class which extends View. Then it will be common functionality for all instances.

Comment: I've added a sample of the code above, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put these two buttons in  some specific layout, and use this layout in other layout by merge tag.